# How to calculate : $\frac{1+i}{1-i}$ and $(\frac{1+\sqrt{3i}}{1-\sqrt{3i}})^{10}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have these problems :

How to calculate : $\frac{1+i}{1-i}$ and $(\frac{1+\sqrt{3i}}{1-\sqrt{3i}})^{10}$

For some reason this is incorrect I'll be glad to understand why, This is what I done :

I used this formula : $(\alpha,\beta)*(\gamma,\delta)=(\alpha\gamma-\beta\delta,\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma)$

And also : $(\alpha,\beta)*(\gamma,\delta)^{-1}=(\alpha,\beta)*(\frac{\gamma}{\gamma^2+\delta^2}-\frac{\delta}{\gamma^2+\delta^2})$

- $$\frac{1+i}{1-i}=\\(1+i)(1-i)^{-1}=\\(1+i)(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i)=\\(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i+\frac{1}{2}i)=\\(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i+\frac{1}{2}i)=\\1+i\\ \\$$
- $$(\frac{1+\sqrt{3i}}{1-\sqrt{3i}})^{10}=\\
  ((1+\sqrt{3i})(1-\sqrt{3i})^{-1})^{10}=\\
  ((1+\sqrt{3i})(\frac{1}{1+3i}+\frac{\sqrt{3i}}{1+3i}i)^{10}=\\
  (\frac{1}{1+3i}-\frac{\sqrt{3i}\sqrt{3i}}{1+3i}i+\frac{\sqrt{3i}}{1+3i}i+\frac{\sqrt{3i}}{1+3i})^{10}=\\
  (\frac{4}{1+3i}+\frac{\sqrt{3i}+\sqrt{3i}}{1+3i})^{10}$$

Now I want to use De-Moivre :

$$tan(args)= \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3i}+\sqrt{3i}}{1+3i})}{\frac{4}{1+3i}}=\frac{(1+3i)(\sqrt{3i}+\sqrt{3i})}{4+12i}=\frac{\sqrt{3i}-3i\sqrt{3i}+\sqrt{3i}+3i\sqrt{3i}}{4+12i}=\frac{\sqrt{3i}+\sqrt{3i}}{4+12i}$$

But I reach to math error, when trying to calculate the args.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In your second problem, is the $i$ really supposed to be included under the square roots?

Comment: @paw88789 Yes, the problem is $$(\frac{1+\sqrt{3i}}{1-\sqrt{3i}})^{10}$$ The $i$ under the square root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you calculated in the first part is not the same quantity as what you asked in the original question:  is the quantity to be computed $$\frac{1-i}{1+i},$$ or is it $$\frac{1+i}{1-i}?$$  Even if it is the latter, you have made a sign error in the fourth line:  it should be $$(1+i)(\tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{i}{2}) = \frac{(1+i)^2}{2} = \frac{1+i+i+i^2}{2} = \frac{2i}{2} = i.$$

For your second question, you need to be absolutely sure that what you mean is $\sqrt{3i}$, rather than $i \sqrt{3}$.  They are not the same.  I suspect the actual question should use the latter, not the former.

Comment: You'r right, I edited the question, I don't understand why I made a sign error, the formula is $-(\beta\delta)$ can you explain?, about the second problem, I absolutely sure that the $i$ is under the square root, however there could be a printing mistake. Do you say that the second question is incorrect? meaning that it there is a mistake in my book.

Comment: I strongly suspect it is an error, because if you want to write such an expression in the form $a + bi$ for real numbers $a, b$, then we would need to write $$\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{3i}}{1-\sqrt{3i}}\right)^{10} = -\frac{2641(1945691+794324\sqrt{6})}{5^{10}} - \frac{682 (4765944+1945691 \sqrt{6})}{5^{10}}i.$$  Whereas, if the intended expression is $$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{1-\sqrt{3}i}\right)^{10},$$ then this has value $$-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i.$$

Comment: Oh, I see I'll contact my professor about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- $$\left(1+i\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i\right)\ne\left(\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\color{red}{\bf -}}_{\small\text{wrong}}\frac{i^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i+\frac{1}{2}i\right)$$
- $$((1+\sqrt{3}i)(1-\sqrt{3}i)^{-1})^{10}=
  (1+\sqrt{3}i)\left(\frac{1}{\color{red}4}+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{\color{red}4}\right)^{10}$$

  ---

Actually both of them are easily solvable by this way:
- $$\begin{align}\frac{1+i}{1-i}&=\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac i{\sqrt2}}{\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac i{\sqrt2}}\\&=\frac{e^{i\pi/4}}{e^{-i\pi/4}}\\&=e^{i\pi/2}\\&=i\end{align}$$
- $$\begin{align}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt3i}{1-\sqrt3i}\right)^{10}&=\left(\frac{\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i}{\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i}\right)^{10}\\&=\left(\frac{e^{i\pi/3}}{e^{-i\pi/3}}\right)^{10}\\&=\left(e^{2i\pi/3}\right)^{10}\\&=e^{20i\pi/3}=e^{i(6\pi+2\pi/3)}\\&=e^{2i\pi/3}\\&=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\end{align}$$

Comment: But the formula is $-(\beta\delta)$, the sign comes from the formula, I don't understand why its incorrect, can you explain?

Comment: @JaVaPG $(\alpha,\beta)*(\gamma,\delta)=(\alpha\gamma - \beta\delta,\alpha\delta + \beta\gamma)$ so $(1+i)(0.5+0.5i)=(1,1)(0.5,0.5)=(1*0.5-1*0.5,1*0.5+1*0.5)=(0,1)$

Comment: Thanks for your explaination, I understand problem $1$, Can you explain in problem $2$ how you managed to get $4$ instand of $1+3i$? using the formula.

Comment: @JaVaPG multiply both numerator and denominator by $(1+\sqrt3 i)$ and then use $(1+\sqrt3i)(1-\sqrt3i)=1^2-(\sqrt3i)^2=1-(-3)=4$